# Mod_Rewrite for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URL structure for Joomla 1.5 changed in version 2.5.

Before it was:

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=587&Itemid=73

Now it's:

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=587&Itemid=114

*Note the id and itemid numbers change based on page and while all pages have an id not all have the Itemid in the url.

While we updated all links in the database lots of people still have the old link structure so we want to edit the htaccess file so if someone enters the old structure it will forward to the right structure.

Simply put any URL entered at example.com with task=view in the url should be replaced with view=article.

Does anyone know a simply way to do this in htaccess, maybe with replace query string method and 301 redirect?

Answer (score 1):

You can match against the query string using mod_rewrite's `RewriteCond` and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Then use the **%** backreferences in a `RewriteRule`

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&task=view&(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&view=article&%2 [R=301,L]
```